# What does nr_vmscan_write track, in layman’s terms?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

`nr_vmscan_write` is a metric that refers to writeback of dirty pages during a scan of the LRU(s), I believe.  As I understand it, there are only a few circumstances where this metric is incremented (in the Kernel's memory management code, `vmscan.c`).

You can find this metric in /proc/pid/vmstat as vmscan_write
Collectd uses it in the vm metrics section.

I am hoping someone with some expertise can explain under what general condition(s) would you expect to see a sharp spike.

This is on a Linux 3.10 Kernel, and typically is followed by the entire swap space becoming used, despite `vm.swappiness` being set to 1.  I also tend to see that the sum total of VmSwap for all pids in /proc/pid/status does not seem to total to the entire swap space (4 G), despite free showing that all 4 G are used.  The total of all pids is closer to 3 G, so it seems 1 G of used swap is not accounted for somehow.

Comment: I believe the answer is that you see this when a lot of allocations are suddenly requested while memory is already under a lot of pressure.  In my case it showed high order fragmentation and direct reclaim occurring.

Comment: More correctly, I believe it's page outs to disk during LRU scans.  Disk writes caused by memory pressure to the virtual memory subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Swap space can be used by tmpfs.  Other than that, memory pressure causing page outs to disk would be a cause of vmscan writes.